# Unexpected token error in reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using react-jsonschema-form to display and validiate form and while creating custom validation found in the Unexpected tocken error in the line which is having "..." syntax. Please find the below code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const SchemaForm = JSONSchemaForm.default;

let schema = {
 type: "string",
title: "FirstName",
minLength: 12,
required: true,
messages: {
required: "Please enter your First name",
minLength: "First name should be > 5 characters"
}
 };

  const MySchemaForm = props => {

  const transformErrors = errors => {
  return errors.map(error => {

  if (error.schema.messages && error.schema.messages[error.name]) {
    return {
      ...error,
      message: error.schema.messages[error.name]
    };
  }
  return error;
 });
 };

 return (
<SchemaForm
  { ...props }
  schema={schema}
  liveValidate
  showErrorList={false}
  transformErrors={transformErrors}
 / >
);
 };

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {formData: {}};
 }
 onSubmit({formData}) {
this.setState({formData});
}
 render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <MySchemaForm formData=""/>
  </div>
);
}
}

React.render(<App />, 
         document.getElementById("app"));
```

Im getting the error at the line where "...error". Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a plugin if you're going to use the `...` rest/spread operator. Here's the babel plugin:

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/